# How to deny access to a file name in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Please Help!
I am trying to forbid visitors to access the following file name ?file=: Only work with my domain like we do Hotlink protection

> domain.com/inscription/?file=

Try this

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^domain.com$      [NC]
>
> RewriteEngine On RewriteRule (^|/)file(/|$) - [F,NC]

but what I have above does not work: I can still access the file from the browser remotely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule :

```
RewriteEngine  on

RewriteCond  %{HTTP_REFERER} !domain\.com$
RewriteCond  %{THE_REQUEST} /inscription/\?file= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Comment: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: There was a space between  `THE` and ` _`  in the condition line. I have fixed it.